# Django Restful API App

Tags: python, django, rest

I made a new API app to serve all the API requests for my web app. So I want to first do something simple and return a DataFrame object in the form of JSON. I am also using the Django Rest Framework Library.

My `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from api import views

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'test', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

My views.py:

```
class UserViewSet(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )

    def get(self):
        queryset = NAV.objects.filter(fund__account_class=0, transmission=3).values('valuation_period_end_date').annotate(
        total_nav=Sum(F('outstanding_shares_par') * F('nav'))).order_by('valuation_period_end_date')
        df = read_frame(queryset, coerce_float=True)
        df.loc[:, 'valuation_period_end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.valuation_period_end_date)
        df.loc[:, 'timestamp'] = df.valuation_period_end_date.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 6
        df.loc[:, 'total_nav'] = df.total_nav
        return JsonResponse(df)
```

But I get the error `AssertionError:`base_name`argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a`.queryset`attribute.` I am new to Django Restful API Framework and was wondering if I am doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to specify a basename when registering the view on your router. Try this (Change `'User'` to something like the name of the model you are querying:

```
router.register(r'test', views.UserViewSet, 'User')
```

For more info on this see here:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/